# parse credentials powershell & validate login

Tags: azure, powershell, validation, credentials

We support 100+ customers for AWS and AZURE.

Because there is no regular need for logging into every customer environment without an issue, our credentials expire periodically.

We are looking to automate the AZURE login with PowerShell.
We will store our credentials in a password protected excel file.

The Excel file will have subscription, jump host, domain name, username & password
in each column.

As we run the script, each subscription and AD credentials should be validated one after other

It will be bad on my part to ask for a script directly. If anyone would be so kind to help me with pointers on how I can achieve this it would be appreciated.

Comment: Storing usernames and passwords in cleartext, even in ostensibly encrypted or password-protected files, is a very bad security practice. I would strongly recommend that you rethink your approach; if you require further advice, you might want to consider posting a well-formulated and specific question in [security.se] - but check their [on-topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) subject information, and also their [How to Ask a Good Question](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Storing usernames and passwords in cleartext, is a very bad security practice.I would recommend you to use Azure key vault or any other alternative approach to store the credential.

Please note that storing any kind of credential is not recommend. But still you have to implement it then you can do something like below:

1) Create azure key vault and store all your information ,user id and password in key vault only.

2) Use Azure MSI or service principal authentication in powershell to authenticate your script with key vault.

3) Access user id and password from the key vault and then finally perform your login .

you can refer below doc for understanding the flow of Azure key vault access.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-powershell

Hope it helps.